# Padding on a:before pseudo element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I am trying to style some links with lines underneath using the :before pseudo element. The link element has some padding that I cannot change. I have set the before position to absolute to show the line, but as I understand, this means the padding of the link gets counted as part of the :before element width. I have tried using `box-sizing: content-box;` but the padding space still gets included.

What I trying to achieve is for the line to only go as far as the link text and not into the padding space.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <a href="">heya</a>
  <a href="">what's up?</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1em;
}
a::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4my5aecj/1/)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the css `calc` 
as : `width: calc(100% - 2em);`

here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/hellooutlook/krgLeq6h/1/

Answer (score 0):

Do it with background and you will have better control:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 1em;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#000,#000) 
    bottom -0.5em center /* position */
    /100% 2px /*width height */
    no-repeat;
  background-origin:content-box; /* this will consider only the content and not the padding */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="">heya</a>
  <a href="">what's up?</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I didn't know about creating the underline with background. Probably would have been better to start off from this in the first place. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `left` and `right` properties (matching the *x*-padding of your anchor) and drop the `width`:

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    padding: 1em;
}

a::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    left: 1rem;
    right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="">heya</a>
    <a href="">what's up?</a>
</div>
```